# Remove the delete and write permissions of a file

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I want to remove the delete and write permissions of a file. I have tried this

```
string fileName = "some_file";
FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);
fSecurity.AddAccessRule (new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.Delete,  AccessControlType.Deny ));
fSecurity.AddAccessRule (new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.Write,  AccessControlType.Deny ));
File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);
```

But it does not seem to work and when I used

```
fSecurity.AddAccessRule (new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRight.Fullcontrol,  AccessControlType.Deny ));
```

It worked but it removes all the permissions of a file. I only want to remove the delete and write permissions of a file.

Could any one tell me how do I remove the write and delete permissions of a file and how do I reset them again?

I am confused how and when to use `AddAccessrule`,`ResetAccesserule` and `Removeaccessrule`. I'm using .net framework 3.5.

Comment: You say "properties" but sample code is about permissions/ACL . Not sure if your "properties" mean "permissions" or your smaple code is wrong.

Comment: I have changed it to permissions .

Comment: It looks like you are adding an access role to deny users, are you sure you don't want to remove this role?